# BAD_EXC_ACCESS checking to see if data exist:SWIFT

Tags: swift, ios8, exc-bad-access, managedobjectcontext

I have a `UITableViewController` that I have data.  If you tap on the row, you can edit the existing data, if you tap on the + in the `UIBarButtonItem`, you add new infomation.  When my Segue passes the *Core Data Object* (vc.managedObjectID) my "detail" view controller checks to see if the firstName field has data or no data.

In *Objective-C*, I would do something like this

```
- (void)refreshInterface
{
    CoreDataHelper *cdh = [CoreDataHelper sharedHelper];
    Cues *existingCues = (Cues*)[cdh.context existingObjectWithID:_cuesNSManagedObjectID error:nil];

    if (!existingCues.cuesName)
    {
        _cueNameTextField.text           = nil;
        self.cueDescriptionTextView.text = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        _cueNameTextField.text           = existingCues.cuesName;
        self.cueDescriptionTextView.text = existingCues.cuesDescription;
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem checking to see if there is any data in firstName:  var firstName = playerInformation.firstName causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS only when adding a new object (meaning playerInformatin is empty), when I tap to see existing data it returns the correct data.  How do I check to see if playerInfomation is empty (new record) or has data (exisiting data) in Swift?

```
func refreshInterface(){

    if managedObjectID != nil {
        var playerInformation = managedObjectContext?.existingObjectWithID(managedObjectID!, error: nil) as? PlayerInformation

        var firstName = playerInformation!.firstName //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        println("firstName \(firstName)")
    }
}
```

prepareForSegue

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "addPlayerInformationDetail" {

            println("addPlayerInformationDetail")

            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext

            let entity  = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity

            let playerInformation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as PlayerInformation?

            var vc  = segue.destinationViewController as PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController

            vc.managedObjectID = playerInformation?.objectID

        } else if segue.identifier == "editPlayerInformationDetail" {


            println("editPlayerInformationDetail")

            var indexPath:NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

            var vc                    = segue.destinationViewController as PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController

            vc.managedObjectID        = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath).objectID

        }
```

Comment: causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional `let` like so:

```
if let firstName = playerInformation?.firstName {
    println("firstName \(firstName)")
}
```

This will only unwrap the optional value if it isn't nil, avoiding the crash.

Comment: `if let firstName = playerInformation?.firstName {
                println("firstName \(firstName)")
            }`
The `if` condition causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @PaulS. Interesting. Try `if let p = playerInformation { var firstName = p.firstName
        println("firstName \(firstName)") }`

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `var firstname` line.  It might be worth nothing that in the Variables View (lower left hand debug pane) `firstName = (String) ""`

Comment: What's the declared type of `firstName`? Is it `NSString!`?

Comment: PlayerInformation is an NSManagedObject, firstName is a String.  Again, when I run the app and select a UITableView cell that has data, even your suggested code works find, and the firstName is printed.

Comment: Try writing just `if playerInformation != nil`, your original code within the `if` statement. If that doesn't work, it's probably a Core Data bug with optional values, and we'll have to look for a workaround.

Comment: I tried the following:         

`var playerInformation = managedObjectContext?.existingObjectWithID(managedObjectID!, error: nil) as? PlayerInformation

        if playerInformation != nil {
            
            var firstName = playerInformation!.firstName //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            println("firstName \(firstName)")
            
        }`
same problem.

Comment: Do you get any error log output? Is the memory address shown by the exception 0x0, or an actual value?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking:  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address 0x0)` in the left hand pane, pretty much all the values are 0

Comment: The problem appears to be that the non-optional `firstName` value is set to nil by Core Data. Changing the type of `firstName` in the declaration of the class to `String!` *might* fix this problem. You could also try removing the `!` from the code on the line where the exception occurs (if that even compiles). This looks like a bug in the Swift compiler or Core Data to me.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason this works:

```
var playerInformation = managedObjectContext?.existingObjectWithID(managedObjectID!, error: nil)
var firstName: AnyObject? = playerInformation?.valueForKey("firstName")
println("firstName \(firstName)")
```

If I subclass the managedObjectContext as PlayerInformation, I would get EXC_BAD_ACCESS